# How to Overlay text over image at left top corner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to have textview over image at top left corner of the Imageview similar to this. how can I do this.
[image]

I have this code but It doesn't do what i want.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="Test"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Also, to make your question better next time you ask you should say what the code is doing and what you expect it to do, rather than just saying "it doesn't do what I want".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `ConstraintLayout`. Here's a simple example. For layering, views are layered in the order listed in the xml so if you want the `TextView` in front put it last in the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Words"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Android Studio Preview]